# Changing date format database (y-m-d) to European (d-m-y) in JS

Tags: javascript

a quick question. I just retrieved dates from a database, but they're obviously in a wrong format for me. In php you have StrToTime, but is there a similar way in Javascript to do this?

I need a D-m-Y format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) will help. Spoilers below for after you’ve tried using them :O

```js
const databaseDate = '2019-06-11';
const [y, m, d] = databaseDate.split('-');
console.log([d, m, y].join('-'));
```